# Live agent chat in bottom corner of page, not popup

Tags: rest-api, liveagent, popup

We're implementing a Salesforce LiveAgent chat for a customer, and they want the chat to appear in the bottom right corner of the page, in a layer, not a popup. My question is: is this even possible while retaining sane chat functonality?

I have succeeded in plucking out the content of the chat popup and sticking it in an iframe which I position at the bottom of the page. However, upon reloading/navigating, the chat naturally needs to be re-opened and restarted by the visitor and the previous chat session is lost. This is not desired.

I have tried to get a session ID from the liveagent API, but that's not possible with an AJAX call since the API seems to be cross-domain protected for some reason (I can't send the headers the API needs). Luckily, one of our backend guys succeeded in getting a session ID via CURL. This is only step 1, however, as now I need to persist the ID of an ongoing chat and automatically reconnect to the same session when the user navigates.

So if it is possible to use LiveAgent chat in the way I have described it, how do I actually do it? Any help is much appreciated, the documentation is vague at best and completely wrong at worst.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old issue but found it while trying to find the answer myself. There is a github repo with an example here:

https://github.com/emoran/Salesforce-Live-Agent-in-same-Browser

But you could potentially do it using the startWithChatWindow() from the LiveAgent API but it is using an iframe on the page and potentially a bit of a hack (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/live_agent_dev/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/live_agent_launching_chat_request_API_startChatWithWindow.htm).

Comment: Yep, theoretically startWithChatWindow() will work with an iframe, but it falls apart when you need to persist the session after a reload or something. We SHOULD be able to get the session ID through the REST api, but that is not available with AJAX because they don't allow CORS.

Comment: Why cant you try the new Salesforce snapins for web. Though its in beta you can check the feasibility

Comment: This was back in the days of classic UI. Yup Snapins are the way to go..